# How to play data stream from android using VLC?

Tags: android, streaming, rtsp, vlc

I'm trying to stream video from the camera on my android device. I've just followed the code in this link: [Android Camera RTSP/RTP Stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959745/android-camera-rtsp-rtp-stream)

It seems the user had a problem with the YUV decoding, to solve this I've used:

parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.RGB_565);

to obtain preview frames on rgb format.

The logs tell that the packets are sent with no error, so what i would like to do next is to play the data stream on VLC player located on a local pc. I introduce the local ip of my pc on the code, so the packets are sent to it. But how to play them????

I'm really newby at this point and any advice could help me a lot.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to publish a stream ip with your android, this part as you are saying it is working fine. While from the PC you can open this from VLC network stream. The missing part is to find out what is the address of this published stream, assuming that the PC has access to this android link by being connected together, same wifi network ...

Comment: Well what exactly does is inject via socket on the local pc. What I've done few momens ago is to set a network deployment on VLC by adding the port rtp://:@9954, which is the UDP port which catches the packets. When the straming is started an error popup appears on VLC telling it is necessary a description in SDP format. Any idea?